# JasperReports & Struts2: custom chart themes

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I'm trying to integrate *JasperReports* in a web application that runs on *Struts2*.
I'm using the *struts2-jasperreports-plugin (2.3.15)*.

To do so I added in my *struts2.xml* the the mapping for the action method and to the image servlet, and I wrote an action that simply takes in input a *jrxml* source file and compiles the report.

Here is the configuration lines i added in *struts2.xml*

```
<package name="jasperreport" namespace="/jasperreports" extends="jasperreports-default">
    <action name="getJasperReport" class="....JasperReportAction" method="getJasperReport">
      <result name="success" type="jasper" >
        <param name="location">jasper/tmp/${outFile}</param>
        <param name="format">${format}</param>
        <param name="imageServletUrl">/servlets/image?image=</param>
      </result>
    </action>
</package>

<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/servlets/image*" />
```

And added in my *web.xml* the mapping for the servlet image:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlets/image</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The action method is reported here:

```
public class JasperReportAction  extends ActionSupport {

    private java.sql.Connection sqlConnection;
    private String sourceFile;
    private String outFile;
    private String format;
    private String reportName;
    private String outputName;


    public JasperReportAction() {
        //initialize the connection...
    }

    //getters and setters..


    public String getJasperReport() {   
        try {
            String reportPath = "jasper/" + reportName;
            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(reportPath,"jasper/tmp/" + outputName + ".jasper");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            logger.log("getJasperReport", e);
            return ERROR;
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

And I call the action with a JQuery load:

```
$("#jasperReport").load("url/getJasperReport.action",
    {
        "sourceFile": "source.jrxml", 
        "outFile"   : "outFile", 
        "format"    : "HTML",           
 });
```

I'm editing my reports with *iReports 5.1.0* and if I create a report where the charts uses one of the default themes, the report is correctly compiled and it is displayed in my web application.
I tried to use a custom template, I've created it and exported the jar using *iReport* and finally put the theme jar under my WEB-INF/lib folder.

When I try to retrieve the report from my application the *Struts* dispatcher gives me the following error:

> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Exception occurred during processing request: null
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   .......

I get this error even if i try to open a report that doesn't use the custom theme. Unless I remove the theme jar.
It seems that no *JasperReports* Exception is thrown during the report compilation, since the logger in the catch block doesn't log anything, But the *jasper* file isn't created.

I've put in my WEB-INF/lib the *jasperreports-chart-themes* jar, I've tried versions 4.0.0 and 5.1.0 but I always get the same error.

When I show the report preview in *iReport* everything works fine.

Can someone tell me if I am missing something to do before using custom chart themes?

Comment: Can you post relevant parts of code and configuration ? (action, web.xml, struts.xml)

Comment: I edited the post and added some info

Comment: I don't know why the exception is raising, but the runtime compilation is heavily discouraged [in the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/jasperreports-tutorial.html): ***"Again, don't use this in production code. You should of course either provide compiled templates, or do some sort of checking to avoid compiling the template on every request."*** My 2 cents: try to adjust your code to make it similar to the one in the tutorial, and once it works, start customizing, if necessary.

Comment: Yes I've read the advice in the documentation, but my intention is to allow the user to upload and change the jrxml source later inside the webapp, so i need to recompile. But I will try to follow your advice, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have found what the problem is.
It was not systematic, but sometimes instead of an *InvocationTargetException* I was having a *ClassNotFoundException*.

I simply needed to add some jars in my webapp *lib* folder. What I needed was:

- the custom theme jar (obviously)
- jasperreports-chart-themes-5.1.0.jar (instead of the 4.0.0)
- castor-1.2.jar

There are newer version of the castor libraries, but some other libraries (maybe jasperreports-chart-themes?) are not compatible with versions newer than 1.2. It seems that the class **CastorException** is searched in the package **org.exolab.castor.core.exceptions** that in the newer versions has been moved to the package **org.exolab.castor.xml**.